# Does Flower of Death add to damage rolls?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I was reading the vampire v20 rule book for celerity and it is slightly unclear on how flower of death works.  The rules for it's effect are as follows:

Once the power is in effect, the vampire’s bonus dice for Dexterity rolls get added to every dice pool for attack the character makes (even if the roll doesn’t use Dexterity) until the end of the scene. Further, even if the Kindred uses some of his Celerity dots for extra actions during the scene, these extra dice are still available.The effect is limited to hand-to-hand or melee weapon attacks — firearms, bows, and other ranged weapons are excluded — but does grant the attacker additional dice for damage rolls.

The only part that is confusing is the last part: "but does grant the attacker additional dice for damage rolls."  Does this mean that flower or death grants the bonus on all melee attack rolls, but NOT damage rolls (It says attack rolls in the power, so the to-hit rolls is my understanding), but for ranged attacks, it does the opposite, and grant the bonus on damage rolls and not the to-hit rolls.  The only other option I see is that it provides the bonus on ALL rolls in combat, to-hit and damage, just not the to-hit on ranged rolls.

If anyone can clear this up and help me make sure of how this works I'd appreciate it.  Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

The effect of the power is to add your rating in Celerity -- so, seven at the very least -- as extra dice for any Brawl or Melee attack-related roll you make during the scene. Trying to hit? Dexterity + Melee + 7. Trying to wrestle someone? Strength + Brawl + 7. Doing damage? Strength + Damage Rating + Extra Successes + 7. It doesn't get diminished by using Celerity for extra actions, and allows you to use Celerity to gain extra damage successes in the way Potence usually does. It doesn't work on defense, and doesn't work with ranged attacks.

Comment: Does it work with parry then?

Comment: Parry is used on defense, so, no. Only for attacking.